# table field in WHERE has multiple values

Tags: mysql, where-clause

What is the proper query for something like this:

```
UPDATE table SET field1 WHERE field2 = val and field3 = val AND val AND val;
```

Wherein field3 has multiple values. Thanks a lot, hope you understand :)

Comment: `val AND val AND val` all three are separate values  or comma separated single string value?

Comment: With an `AND` you will have to write it out completely, with an `OR` you can use and `IN` statement

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The SQL IN condition (sometimes called the IN operator) allows you to
>   easily test if an expression matches any value in a list of values. It
>   is used to help reduce the need for multiple OR conditions in a
>   SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, or DELETE statement.

```
UPDATE table SET field1=newVal WHERE field2 = val and field3 In (val1, val2, val3);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE tableName SET fieldName = newFieldValue 
WHERE field1 = val1 AND field2 = val2 AND (
    field3 = val3 OR field3 = val4 OR field3 = val5
);
```